# Quarternions in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am programming an 6DOF space-shooter in 3D with Unity and C#. I am using mouse and keyboard for the movement. With the mouse I use Quarterions for the rotation in X, Y and Z axis.

I tried the following code:

```
void Update()
{
    float test = Input.GetAxis("Pitch");
    float test2 = Input.GetAxis("Yaw");

    float test3 = Input.GetAxis("Roll");

    rotX += test;
    Quaternion q1 = Quaternion.AngleAxis(rotX, Vector3.right);


    rotY += test2;
    Quaternion q2 = Quaternion.AngleAxis(rotY, Vector3.up);

    roll += test3;
    Quaternion q3 = Quaternion.AngleAxis(roll, Vector3.forward);

    transform.rotation = q1 * q2 * q3;
}
```

The code works, but not for all the angles. It looks that over every 90 degrees the movement is not correct (x-axis and y-axis turn around). I expect that this code works for every angle, what is wrong in this code?

Comment: As quayernions are noncommunative, so `q1 * q2 * q3` isn't the same as `q2 * q1 * q3`. I suck at quaternions, so I don't know if you have those 3 in the right order. You might not. Or you could be incorrectly arriving at those values (ie your compassion might be creating gimbal lock). I'm not sure.

Comment: If I try for example transform.rotation = q2 * q1 * q3, then I get the problem with gimbal lock.

Comment: Example ordering is an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Zambari said, make sure you're rotating around *local* axes.  But also, you seem to be storing the orientation in Euler angles, `rotX, rotY, rotZ` and then setting that as the absolute rotation.  This is bad.  What you want is to apply the delta/modification to the transform's stored quaternion:

```
void Update() {

    var yaw = Quaternion.AngleAxis(Input.GetAxis("Yaw"), transform.up);
    var pitch = Quaternion.AngleAxis(Input.GetAxis("Pitch"), transform.right);            
    var roll = Quaternion.AngleAxis(Input.GetAxis("Roll"), transform.forward);

    transform.rotation = transform.rotation * yaw * pitch * roll;
}
```

**note:** the order of multiplication on the final line may be incorrect.

After saying all that, if all you want is to control your character, try (angles in degrees):

```
transform.Rotate(xAngle, yAngle, zAngle, Space.Self);
```

Comment: it works!  The only thing is that when I move the mouse (for example 10 times) on the same location, I get a little drift and the object is not on the same position anymore.

Comment: I'd assume that's mechanical or analog-to-digital error and not something you can fix with code.

Answer (score 1):

You are using absolute (world) vectors as your frame of reference. change Vector3.up to transform.up, Vector3.forward to transform.forward and Vector3.right to transform right, this way you will be rotating along local axis, and gimbal lock should be less problematic.

Order of operations will still matter, but for relatively small delta it should work as expected.

I think you are doing the right thing multiplying the quaternions before assigning the new rotation, otherwise each local vector would change with each operation - the behaviour would be slightly different